# How to zip a file using symfony

Tags: php, symfony, base64, zip

I uploaded a file and I want to zip it and then encode it in base64. The upload is going well. But when it comes to zipping, I encounter errors.
Here is my controller

FileController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use App\Entity\Upload;
use App\Form\UploadType;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\Exception\FileException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Symfony\Component\String\Slugger\SluggerInterface;

class FileController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/home", name="accueil")
     */
    public function index(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $manager, SluggerInterface $slugger)
    {

        $upload = new Upload();

        $form = $this->createForm(UploadType::class, $upload);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $manager->persist($upload);
            $manager->flush();


            $uploadedFile = $form->get('document')->getData();

            $originalFilename = pathinfo($uploadedFile->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            $safeFilename = $slugger->slug($originalFilename);
            $newFilename = $safeFilename.'-'.uniqid().'.'.$uploadedFile->guessExtension();
            
            
            try {
                $uploadedFile->move(
                    $this->getParameter('upload_directory'),
                    $newFilename
                );
            } catch (FileException $e) {
                // ... handle exception if something happens during file upload
            }

            $zip = new \ZipArchive();
            if ($zip->open('doc1.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE) == TRUE)
            {
                // Add files to the zip file
                $zip->addFile($uploadedFile);
             
                // All files are added, so close the zip file.
                $zip->close();
            }
            // Get the file and convert into string 
            $zip_f = file_get_contents('doc1.zip'); 
                  
            // Encode the zip file string data into base64 
            $data = base64_encode($zip_f);  
                
            // Display the output 
            echo $data; 


            $upload->setDocument($newFilename);
            return $this->redirectToRoute('accueil');

        }

        return $this->render('file/index.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
}
```

This is the message that i recieve when i run it:

*Attempted to load class "ZipArchive" from namespace "App\Controller".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?*

Comment: `ZipArchive::CREATE` <- you want `\ZipArchive::CREATE` instead, as [it's a class that belongs to the language and exists in the root namespace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php), so since you're in a different one (`App\Controller`), you need to target it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

After installation is done and check your ZipArchive class is exist with this code

```
var_dump(class_exists('ZipArchive'));
```

if it returns true then you just add

```
use ZipArchive;
```

put it after your namespace
and then put this code

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
```

on where you are want to put

Comment: It works, but i have a new error. "Warning: file_get_contents(doc1.zip): failed to open stream: No such file or directory"

Comment: @OrlaineLekaneGuetsa You should mark this as the accepted answer if it did solve the problem.